# Remove the Numbers from file name when using Photoshop : File > Layers to Files

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Ive got a PSD with multiple files that need to be exported all at the same size and quality for a presentation.

For this i have each image on its own layer and use **File > Layers to Files** I pre name the layers a descritive name and use the prefix section of the layers to files window to add in the project name.

So i end up with a filename like this : PROJECT NAME - _0001_LAYERNAME.jpg

Is there a way i can get it to not output the layer number eg. ***0001***

Comment: For anyone else looking into this ... easiest solution is to edit the script. It only takes a few minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in Photoshop as far as I can tell.

This is however possible in Adobe Bridge using `Batch Rename`

First, open Bridge and go to `Tools` `Batch Rename`  and then from the preset dropdown select `String Modification` Then check the `Use Regular Expression` checkbox. Now you can add RegEx to find and replace the pieces you want.

Here's a screenshot, I've included the RegEx I used to get rid of the numbers as well, you may need to change/refine it. (Check out the Current/New Filename at the bottom of my screenshot). I've also unchecked `Replace All` you may or may not need that depending on how you want the RegEx to run.

[image]

**I used Bridge CS5.1 for this, I assume it works similarly in higher versions of Bridge**

I figure I'll also try to explain the RegEx (`\_[0-9]*`) a bit since it's all magic.

[`\`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash) escapses the `_` so regEx takes it literally. This eliminates the preceding underscore and also helps establish where RegEx should start replacing.

Next I wrote [`[0-9]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set) this will look for any characters that are `0`, `9` and any inbetween.

Lastly I added an [`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk) so that the [`[0-9]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set) pattern would go indefinitely, until we hit a character that doesn't match the pattern (making sure we get all 4 digits)

[Here's a helpful guide from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)